# jquery is not working in IE and giving error

Tags: jquery, validation

I have jquery validation code which is working fine in ff but the same code is not working in Internet Explorer. There is no error when I run same script in FF but there is an error when i run same scritp in Internet explorer the error is as follows

Error: Expected identifier, string or number
code: 0

I cant able to understand this problem please any one have guidence on this. I cant paste code here cause the code is very big?

so please any one came accross such error before or any one know any possibility due to that  such error came.
please help me friends!

Comment: Without some code, I can't say much more than it looks like you have a syntax error somewhere. Check your parentheses, commas, braces, etc. Can you identify a section of code where this is occurring?

Comment: could you post a link to your js file?

Comment: You'll *have* to post code here to get satisfactory answers. Try removing as much code as you can to the smallest amount possible where the problem is still exhibited. Then post it here...

Comment: ...or as Luke suggested, a link to your js file

Comment: Thanks to all of you friends! I spotted the cause of error you all are right its a syntax error. By mistake I had added an extra comma in my JQUERY validation code due to that it was giving an error. Thank you all friends for your guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the others say, without your code it's pretty hard to answer.

However... There is one thing that I can think of that throws IE into a fit while behaving correctly in Firefox, Safari, etc.

If you put an extra comma at the end of a list or object definition, it will trigger that error in IE.

Check and make sure you don't have an extra ',' before an ending curly brace.

Comment: Thanks to all of you friends! I spotted the cause of error you all are right its a syntax error. By mistake I had added an extra comma in my JQUERY validation code due to that it was giving an error. Thank you all friends for your guidance.

Comment: That's great... Any chance you could select my answer again?  I finally was able to vote up and down and now I'm back to 1.  ha...